# Correct implementation of circuit breaker in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, circuit-breaker

I'm really struggling to implement circuit breaker pattern correctly in my application. Here is the code I am stuck at:

**ReservationController**

```
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "stock_request_breaker")
    public ReservationDto addReservation(@RequestBody ReservationDto reservationDto) {
        return reservationService.addReservation(reservationDto);
    }
```

**ReservationService**

```
    public ReservationDto addReservation(ReservationDto reservationDto) {
        List<String> reservationBooksIsbns = reservationDto.getReservationItemList().stream().map(reservationItem -> String.valueOf(reservationItem.getBookIsbn())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<StockItemResponseDto> stockItemResponseDtoList = fetchItemsFromStockServiceByISBNs(reservationBooksIsbns);
        if (reservationBooksIsbns.size() != stockItemResponseDtoList.size()) {
            throw new ProductNotAvailableException("Not all products from the list are available in stock. Please verify your request and try again.");
        }
        performCheckIfThereIsEnoughItemsInStock(reservationDto, stockItemResponseDtoList);
        return reservationMapper.map(saveReservationToDatabase(reservationDto));
    }

    private List<StockItemResponseDto> fetchItemsFromStockServiceByISBNs(List<String> isbns) {
        Object[] rawResponse = webClientBuilder.build().get()
                .uri(String.format("http://apiGateway/api/stock?objectIsbns=%s", String.join(",", isbns)))
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new ExternalServiceErrorException("Sorry")))
                .bodyToMono(Object[].class)
                .block();
        return Arrays.stream(rawResponse)
                .map(object -> mapper.convertValue(object, StockItemResponseDto.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Reservation saveReservationToDatabase(ReservationDto reservationDto) {
        Reservation reservation;
        reservationDto.getReservationItemList().forEach(reservationItem -> reservationItem.setTimestampFrom(Instant.now().getEpochSecond()));
        reservationDto.getReservationItemList().forEach(reservationItem -> reservationItem.setTimestampUntil(Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1) * 30));
        if (reservationRepository.findByUserEmail(reservationDto.getUserEmail()).isEmpty()) {
            reservation = reservationMapper.map(reservationDto);
        } else {
            Optional<Reservation> reservationOptional = reservationRepository.findByUserEmail(reservationDto.getUserEmail());
            Reservation reservationNew = reservationMapper.map(reservationDto);
            reservation = reservationOptional.get();
            reservation.getReservationItemList().addAll(reservationNew.getReservationItemList());
        }

        return reservationRepository.save(reservation);
    }

    private void performCheckIfThereIsEnoughItemsInStock(ReservationDto reservationDto, List<StockItemResponseDto> stockItemResponseDtoList) {
        for (ReservationItem reservationItem : reservationDto.getReservationItemList()) {
            Optional<StockItemResponseDto> currentStockItem = stockItemResponseDtoList.stream()
                    .filter(stockItem -> Objects.equals(stockItem.getIsbn(), reservationItem.getBookIsbn()))
                    .distinct().findFirst();
            if (currentStockItem.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ProductDoesNotExistException("Product with isbn: " + reservationItem.getBookIsbn() + " does not exist in our stock.");
            }
            StockItemResponseDto stockItemResponseDto = currentStockItem.get();
            if (stockItemResponseDto.getQuantityInStock() < reservationItem.getQuantity()) {
                throw new ProductNotAvailableException("There is not enough books in stock. Faulty ISBN:" + stockItemResponseDto.getIsbn());
            }

        }
    }
```

**Circuit breaker properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
management.health.ratelimiters.enabled=true

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.stock_request_breaker.failure-rate-threshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.stock_request_breaker.minimum-number-of-calls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.stock_request_breaker.automatic-transition-from-open-to-half-open-enabled=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.stock_request_breaker.wait-duration-in-open-state=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.stock_request_breaker.permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.stock_request_breaker.sliding-window-size=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.stock_request_breaker.sliding-window-type=count_based
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator=true
```

And the problem with this implementation is:

- when I hit the endpoint "addReservation" with correct data and stockservice is up - everything works fine
- when I hit the endpoint "addReservation" with correct data but stockservice is down - I get error 503 with message "Sorry" (as meant with onStatus isError) and after 5 requests the fastfailing starts - this is fine too
- **but when i when I hit the endpoint "addReservation" with data that would produce the ProductNotAvailableException for example**, it also allows only 5 request before fastfailing, eventhough the communication between services works fine - it is reservationService which throws the exception so it should not trigger circuit breaker fastfailing, but it does.

Is my implementation incorrect? What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Following changes worked:

instead of one fallback method I implemented 3 methods:

```
    public ReservationDto fallback( ReservationDto reservationDto, CallNotPermittedException connectException) {
        throw new ExternalServiceErrorException("Your request has not been finished. Please try again later");
    }

    public ReservationDto fallback( ReservationDto reservationDto, ConnectException connectException) {
        throw new ExternalServiceErrorException("Your request has not been finished. Please try again later");
    }
    public ReservationDto fallback( ReservationDto reservationDto, WebClientResponseException webClientResponseException) {
        throw new ExternalServiceErrorException("Your request has not been finished. Please try again later");
    }
```

and added the exceptions that I'm throwing (i.e. ProductNotAvailableException) to the application properties as:

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.stock_request_breaker.ignore-exceptions[1]

It is working but still I would like to know opinion of someone more experienced if this is correct.